# How to Choose Category In Form then show list of category.sizes to choose

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have 3 models products, category, and size.

In my Products new view, I can choose a category.

**When i choose a category i want the category sizes to show below it as a tick box list. How do you do this?. Example: Someone might choose Jeans as the category then below will show all the sizes for jeans as a tick box**

Thank you in advance for any help.

Here is my Product view

```
<div class="container">
  <div class=“row”>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-body">
          <%= simple_form_for @product, html: { multipart: true } do |f| %>
            <%= f.input :image, label:"Choose Image"%>
            <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.order(:name), :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
            <%= f.input :title, label:"Title"%>
            <%= f.input :price, label:"Price"%>
            <%= f.input :description,label:"Description" %>
            <%= f.input :tag_list,label:"Tags - Seperate tags using comma ','. 5 tags allowed per product" %>
            <%= f.button :submit, "Create new product", class: "btn-lg btn-success" %>
          <% end %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Product model

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_taggable

    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :category

  has_many :product_sizes

    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 30 }
    validates :description, presence: true, length: { maximum: 2000 }
    validates :category, :user_id, :price, presence: true

    has_attached_file :image, styles: { large: "600x600", medium: "250x250", thumb:"100x100#"}
    validates_attachment_content_type :image, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

Category model

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_ancestry

  has_many :products
  has_many :sizes

  validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 20 }, uniqueness: true

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :sizes, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Size model

```
class Size < ActiveRecord::Base
    validates :title, presence: true, length: { maximum: 15 }
    validates :title, uniqueness: true

  belongs_to :category
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I see at least 2 possible options (depends on amount of categories & performance).

**1)** You should create checkboxes and wrap them in a hidden div & show them if specific category is selected. For ex:

Modify form:

```
#load @categories in controller (@categories = Category.preload(:sizes).order(:name))
<%= f.collection_select :category_id, @categories, :id, :name, include_blank: true, :prompt => "Select One Category" %>
<% @categories.each do |category| %>
  <div class='sizes_container' id ='sizes_container_for_<%= category.id %>' style='display:none'>
   <% category.sizes.each do |size| %>
     <!-- place checkboxes here -->
   <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Add Js (Js on change will show proper checkboxes)

```
$('#product_category_id').on('change', function(){
  $('.sizes_container input').hide();
  $('.sizes_container input').removeAttr('checked');
  $('#sizes_container_for_' + $(this).val()).show();
})
```

**2)** On select change you should make an [ajax call](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to server, fetch sizes & build checkboxes for them

Comment: Thanks i will take a look at this tonight. Cheers for your reply.